# Build visual studio C++ project within solution for multiple platforms

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, build, msbuild

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains multiple C# projects and a C++ project.

The C++ project is properly configured to build both for x64 and win32 (has separate output directories, proper binaries referred for 32 and 64 and so on) and default configuration is x64. C# projects are configured for Any CPU.

How can I configure my solution to build the C++ project for both x64 and win32 when building the entire solution?

P.S.: Batch build won't do the job for this case because I need to configure it in a way anyone clones the repo will build properly without any additional settings

Comment: l think you can use `Batch Build` for your solution by Right-click on your solution and choose `Batch Build`.And then config these C++ projects both  for `x64` and win32 and then build click Build. And you then when you open your solution, `Debug/Release` folder is just for `win32` while `x64` folder` is just for `x64`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I configure my solution to build the C++ project for both x64
>   and win32 when building the entire solution?

Please use **Batch Build** to build your solution.

**1)** First Right-click on your solution and choose **Batch Build**.

**2)** Second, check the C++ project which you want to build. You can then check both 64-bit and 32-bit for the project, and you can also select `Debug` or `Release` for the **Configuration**. Finally, click Build or Rebuild to generate different versions of the output files at the same time.

[image]

**3)** When you finish, please open the solution folder. In my side, `Debug` or `Release` folder is just for **32-bit** while `x64` folder is just for **64-bit**.

[image]

**Update 1**

Since you do not want to config VS settings and then use Batch Build, l think you can use custom build target in the `xxxx.vcxproj` file.

**Please** add these targets into `xxxx.vcxproj` of all C++ Projects in the whole solution.

```
<Target Name="BuildFunction" AfterTargets="Build">
    <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Platform=x64;PlatFormTarget=x64" RunEachTargetSeparately="true"  />
    <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'"   Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Platform=Win32;PlatFormTarget=x86" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="CleanAll" AfterTargets="Clean">
    <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='Win32'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Clean" Properties="Platform=x64;PlatFormTarget=x64" RunEachTargetSeparately="true"  />
    <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)'=='x64'"   Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Targets="Clean" Properties="Platform=Win32;PlatFormTarget=x86" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />

  </Target>
```

These targets depends on `Build` or `Clean` target. So when you build the project, they will always execute later and build the project into the other version.

Besides, this method is tied to your solution, so when someone else clones your solution, Build directly from your script or click **Build** in VS IDE and then you see the `x64` and `x86` versions of the files in the solution.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks, but with this solution, anyone who clones the repo will have to do this. And since we use scripts to build the solutions, I need to be able to build both when building from scripts

Comment: Sorry for not aware of your new requirements. And l think you can use some custom targets into `xxx.vcxproj` file of all C++ projects, then just use your build script or just click `Build` and you will see `x64` and `x86` version of  the output files.

Comment: Thank you very much! :D

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT The MSBuild targets stuff works for me, except now I get an MSB4006 error when I build the .vcxproj as part of my solution (as opposed to no error when just building the .vcxproj by itself).  The .vcxproj has to be a dependency of one of the C# projects, and I think it's related to that.  But the build completes successfully, just that it reports the error.  Any way to get rid of this error?

Comment: The MSBuild Solution seems to cause the other platform to be built with the settings of the first platform - e.g. any platform-specific defines or options are based on the originally built platform this way...