# How to create multiple assets (dll) for one project with msbuild depend on Constants value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019.

I know we can build one project with multiple configurations, and have a dll per configuration, for example we can have one dll for the Debug configuration of our project and we can have one dll for the Release configuration of our project.

But my question is how to have multiple dlls for one project based on `DefineConstants`, for example one dll when we `<DefineConstants>ML_HOOSHANG</DefineConstants>` and have another dll for this project without define this constant?

Another question is how to package this project with hold all of these dlls per definition of our define constants?

Another question is, can I force Visual Studio (msbuild) to generate all dlls per build request?

Is [UsingTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/usingtask-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) useful for this purpose? or not?

Is there anyway to change `DefineConstants` per `UsingTask`?

Comment: What does this mean exactly "*and have dll per configuration*" do you mean assembly, or class library, or third-party dll,

Comment: @MichaelRandall it means we can have one dll for release and have another dll for debug and etc. it means we can have assembly per configuration

Comment: So when its in debug mode, you create a different assembly, then to when you're in release mode? A different name or something? a different location?

Comment: @MichaelRandall in different location. this is just example, and we can do it now, and it is very popular, for achieving this, we just change build configuration and have another assemblies in another location, for example I have one assembly in `bin/debug` and have another in `bin/release`

Comment: I don't think you can do this by constant, but obviously you can do it by configuration  (as you know)

Comment: @MichaelRandall I hope we can do this by some way :)

Comment: @sorosh_sabz Hi friend, any update for this issue? Just checking in to see if the issue still persists you. Also, not sure if my answer can make some help, you can check it :)

Answer (score 3):

> How to create multiple assets (dll) for one project with msbuild
> depend on Constants value?

You may get some hint from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59833732/10910450). **Batch build** in VS2019 is something that can help for your issue.

Possible direction:

1. Create one new project named `TestBatchBuild`. Right click `Solution=>Configuration Manager` and create new project configuration `NewDebug` and `NewRelease`.(Copy settings from `Debug` and `Release`)

[image]

Now right click solution=>`batch build` we can see:

[image]

2. Then let's edit the project file(xx.csproj) and we can find four `PropertyGroup`. Add `<DefineConstants>ML_HOOSHANG</DefineConstants>` to `NewDebug` and `NewRelease` PropertyGroup and **Save ALL**.

Now building with `NewDebug` equals to build with `Debug+DefineConstants`. And building with `NewRelease` equals to build with `Release+DefineConstants`. Now let's go batch build page, we can build four assemblies at one time. (Debug+nodef..., Debug+def...,Release+nodef...,Release+def...). Hope all above helps.