# Reference a project in Visual Studio and build it for a specific platform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, csproj

I have a project A which is supposed to be built for x86 and it depends on another project B which is built for x64. I can build it as it is of course but I would like no runtime issues.

So the idea is for me to set project A up so that if I want to build it for x86 I can reference project B but have it built for x86 and if I want to build project A for x64 then I reference project B but have it built for x64. Is this possible?

I put a condition in the .csproj of Project A like:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' ">

    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project B\projB.csproj">
      <Project>{678c5dc7-7a1c-45g3-bffe-a4754c64f027}</Project>
      <Name>projB</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>

<!-- x64 specific referneces -->
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">

    <ProjectReference Include="..\Project B\projB.csproj">
      <Project>{678c5dc7-7a1c-45g3-bffe-a4754c64f027}</Project>
      <Name>projB</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

But I don't know how to have that referenced project build for a specific platform. I know I could just take the .dlls of the two versions and apply a condition for normal references but wanted to see if this is viable. Is it possible? Would I need two separate identical projects but with different target platforms to do this?

Would appreciate if you could help me, thanks!

Comment: *"The idea is for me to set project A up so that if I want to build it for x86 I can reference project B but have it built for x86 and if I want to build project A for x64 then I reference project B but have it built for x64. Is this possible?"* -- **Say this again?**  This is standard way `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">` But there is also `when/then` -- `<When Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'"> . . . `

Comment: if your dependency is x64, you can build with no issue. But you will have runtime issues. You can build with x64.

Comment: When you build a solution with multiple projects, `$(Platform)` is passed to all of them and they should know either to build for x86 or x64. There should never be a need to modify project references in a way above. Read more in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Reference a project in Visual Studio and build it for a specific
>   platform

**Project Reference** is quite different. And What you provide is to build a project on different platforms based on project **A**. Project **B** will not use the corresponding version of platform to build Project B according to the platform change in **A**.

And **Project Reference** is actually to build project B first and then build project **A** , Reference the corresponding Project **B**. It needs to be configured again.

**Update**

In your situation, when build project A, it has a condition like `Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' "`, it is only based on the current platform of project A, but this parameter cannot be passed to project B to compile the project as `x86`. So you should

**Therefore**, you need to manually change the platform of **B** to achieve your goal.

**Solution**

**1)** `Build`-->`Configuration Manager` and change like these to build your project.

[image]

or

[image]

**2)** When you build Porject **A** with `x86`, you should first change Project **B** to `x86` platform and when you do the same with `x64`, you should also do the same operation to Project B.

Right-click on your project A and B-->`Properties`-->`Build`--> change **Platform target** to both x64 or x86.

**And** then you can get the same platform output file in project A ouputpath folder.

**In addition**, you can try to build Project B based on `x64`, `x86` platform at the same time(could refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827393/build-visual-studio-c-project-within-solution-for-multiple-platforms/59833732#59833732)) and then use like your xml code in Project A(according to x64 or x86 platform) to reference(assembly reference) the corresponding project B.dll.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I needed! Apparently I was doing this wrong and I somehow thought that Project A would give Project B its target platform information!

Really informative answer thanks :)